# Embedding issue / All messages send at once

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm having this issue where all my embeds are together. How do I separate them?

[image]

My issue is that every time I run the embeds send together, I know the issue but how do I fix it?

I've already tried to add those little (;) things that supposedly ends the line. I'm new to discord.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate files with their own command properties such as `yesben.js` and create them,

```
var yesben = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle("Ben says..")
   .setDescription("Yes")
   .setImage()
   .setTimestamp()
   .setColor()

   message.channel.send(yesben) // if this is a v12 discord.js
   message.channel.send({embeds: [yesben]}) //if this is a v13 discord.js
```

You can make them as array too:

```
var array = ["Yes", "No", "Augh", "Hohoho"]
var math = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle("Ben says..")
   .setDescription(array[math])
   .setImage() //If you create like this, idk how to send the image same with array
   .setTimestamp()
   .setColor()

   message.channel.send(embed) // if this is a v12 discord.js
   message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]}) //if this is a v13 discord.js


You might get an error like `empty string` because of your `setDescription`
```

All you have to do is to make it as string

```
.setDescription(`${array[math]}`)
```